# OrientDB: how to obtain IDs from group by?

Tags: sql, group-by, aggregate-functions, orientdb

I've created very simple class named `TestEntity: {id: integer,ts: datetime}` and insert few records:

**select from TestEntity**

```
@rid    @version    @class  ts  id

\#12:0  1   TestEntity  2014-07-17 12:47:35 0

\#12:1  2   TestEntity  2014-07-17 12:48:33 0

\#12:2  1   TestEntity  2014-07-16 12:49:06 0

\#12:3  1   TestEntity  2014-07-17 12:49:34 1

\#12:4  1   TestEntity  2014-07-15 12:49:59 1

When I try to do aggregation query with group by "**select max(ts),@rid from TestEntity group by id**" I see the following result:

\#-2:1  0   #12:2   2014-07-17 12:48:33

\#-2:4  0   #12:4   2014-07-17 12:49:34
```

It found the last date correctly (the same works for `min(ts)`). But the `@rid` is incorrect. And, suprisingly, another query with min gives same rids: 12:2, 12:4:

**select min(ts),@rid from TestEntity group by id**

```
\#-2:1  0   \#12:2  2014-07-16 12:49:06

\#-2:4  0   \#12:4  2014-07-15 12:49:59
```

My questions is, what am I doing wrong? What I need to do to group documents by integer `id` (can have duplicates) and find the latest date for each one, and obtain document id (`@rid`) for each document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation, I tried two another variants:

select from (select from TestEntity order by ts asc) group by id

```
@rid    @version    @class  id  ts
#12:3   1   TestEntity  1   2014-07-17 12:49:34
#12:1   2   TestEntity  0   2014-07-17 12:48:33
```

select from (select from TestEntity order by ts desc) group by id

```
@rid    @version    @class  id  ts
#12:4   1   TestEntity  1   2014-07-15 12:49:59
#12:2   1   TestEntity  0   2014-07-16 12:49:06
```

They give me correct results. I think I need to test with bigger datasets.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select min(ts),@rid from ( select from TestEntity order by ts ) group by id
```

In this way you apply your against an ordered result set.

Comment: Have you tried to execute this query? It gives completely incorrect result. Only one line, actually:

#-2:0 0 #12:3 2014-07-15 12:49:59

And even in this line @rid doesn't match with ts. :(